# Why can you call permit on the return value of require for rail's params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm learning rails and came across this line:

```
params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation)
```

Looking at the source for `require`, as seen here~

```
def require(key)
  return key.map { |k| require(k) } if key.is_a?(Array)
  value = self[key]
  if value.present? || value == false
    value
  else
    raise ParameterMissing.new(key)
  end
end
```

--it either returns a `self[key]`, which is a value indexed from the params, or else raises an exception. It does *not* return the params instance itself. So why can you call `permit` on the return value?

Comment: Why shouldn't you be able to call `permit` on that? (hint: look at the type of that value)

Comment: What @SergioTulentsev said. You may be misunderstanding what `self[key]` means take a look [Here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/strong_parameters.rb#L615) and you will note that it returns an `ActionController::Parameters` object. (which does define [`permit`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/strong_parameters.rb#L592))

Comment: Ohhh it's overloaded!!! Thank you so much, I will watch out for that going forward. I wish there were a way to "go to declaration" with operators, but I guess I will have to just click a method on the class and then search for `[]` or whatever it is.

Comment: @temporary_user_name github offers navigation now and also in a rails console you can type `ActionController::Parameters.new({}).method(:[]).source_location` this will provide you with the file and line number where the method is defined (as long as it is not defined dynamically

Comment: Following the source though, it looks like `[]` calls `convert_hashes_to_parameters`, which calls `convert_value _to_parameters`, which just returns `value` unchanged if it isn't a hash or array. So I'm still failing to find where the conversion to a params instance happens!

Comment: @temporary_user_name `self.class.new(value)` is the branch for `Hash` and `Array` just maps it's element ( likely to be Hash)

Comment: @temporary_user_name assume the following in your example: params is `{user: { email: "xyz@abc.com", password: "1243", password_confirmation: "1234"}}` when you call `require(:user)` then `self[:user] #=> { email: "xyz@abc.com", password: "1243", password_confirmation: "1234"}` which is a `Hash` and thus follows `self.class.new({ email: "xyz@abc.com", password: "1243", password_confirmation: "1234"})`. Does that make sense?

Comment: That does make sense! The example I was stuck on, though, is where params is simpler, something like `{username: "godowsky"}`, then `self[:username] #=> "godowsky"`, which is a string rather than a hash or array, so it just gets returned as is-- and therefore doesn't seem to be a params object.

Comment: @temporary_user_name correct and in that instance you cannot call permit because there is nothing nested to permit; however that case would also not raise an error for unpermitted parameter and one would not generally "require" anything either because it either is or it isn't no need for further introspection

Comment: Ah ha! Thank you.